# Using ListIterator to move back and forth over a LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I have a LinkedList over which I need to iterate back and forth multiple times. I am using it to keep track of a series of pages in a workflow that will be created dynamically.  This does not behave as I would expect.  Given this example:

```
LinkedList<String> navigationCases;
navigationCases.add("page1");
navigationCases.add("page2");
navigationCases.add("page3");
navigationCases.add("page4");

ListIterator navigationItr = navigationCases.listIterator();
navigationItr.next(); // Returns page1
navigationItr.next(); // Returns page2
navigationItr.previous(); //Returns page2 again
navigationItr.next(); //Returns page2 again
```

I thought perhaps I was building my list incorrectly, or using the Iterator wrong, but after reading the documentation, this seems to be by design:

**A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().**

And:

**(Next) Returns the next element in the list. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the list, or intermixed with calls to previous to go back and forth. (Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)**

So after reading this, it is clear why my code is behaving the way it does.  I just don't understand why it should work this way.  Even remove seems to be bending over backwards to accommodate this implementation:

**Note that the remove() and set(Object) methods are not defined in terms of the cursor position; they are defined to operate on the last element returned by a call to next() or previous().**

Conceptually, a LinkedList seemed to model my workflow cases pretty well, but I can't use an Iterator that behaves this way.  Am I missing something here, or should I just write my own class maintain a list of cases and navigate through them?

Comment: Why can't you "use an iterator that behaves this way"?  The rest of the world does.  Just accept how it works and leverage it as it was intended to be used.

Comment: It behaves this way because it makes iterating and removing by starting from the end work exactly the same way as iterating and removing by starting from the beginning.

Comment: @Madbreaks How is this use case different from the way it was "intended to used" then?  How do I account for the "special" case of asking for the previous element immediately after asking for the next? Or asking for next immediately after asking for the previous?

Comment: @JBNizet That makes sense.  I can at least see why it would be implemented this way, but I think I will not be able to use a LinkedList for this problem.  Or at the very least, I'll need to write my own ListIterator.

Comment: If you must, wrap the core functionality in your own logic that calls `iterator.previous().previous()` (pseudo obviously) when you ask for `myIterator.previous()`

Comment: @Madbreaks You only have to call previous twice when the previous operation was next().  Otherwise you only call it once.  Hence my frustration :)

Comment: This is seriously frustrating behaviour. Took me hours to reproduce and debug an issue containing this code.

Comment: This is poorly documented behavior and is clearly attributed to a poor API design decision. If the iterator doesn't explicitly point to a single item, there should also be no `remove()` method as this doesn't distinguish whether the 'next' or 'previous' item should be removed. It really should have been designed with methods called `removeNext()` and `removePrevious()` so that the behavior of `next()` and `previous()` would be as expected. I recommend not using ListIterator at all and instead writing a simple iterator by hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do your job:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String> ();

        list.add ("1"); list.add ("2"); list.add ("3"); list.add ("4");

        final MyIterator<String> it = new MyIterator (list.listIterator());

        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next ());
        System.out.println(it.next ());
        System.out.println(it.previous ());
        System.out.println(it.previous ());
        System.out.println(it.next ());
    }

    public static class MyIterator<T> {

        private final ListIterator<T> listIterator;

        private boolean nextWasCalled = false;
        private boolean previousWasCalled = false;

        public MyIterator(ListIterator<T> listIterator) {
            this.listIterator = listIterator;
        }

        public T next() {
            nextWasCalled = true;
            if (previousWasCalled) {
                previousWasCalled = false;
                listIterator.next ();
            }
            return listIterator.next ();
        }

        public T previous() {
            if (nextWasCalled) {
                listIterator.previous();
                nextWasCalled = false;
            }
            previousWasCalled = true;
            return listIterator.previous();
        }

    }   
}
```

And a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/nO3Rmh) for it.

Comment: Yes, I don't see any way around having to remember the previous operation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ListIterator was designed to behave this way. See the conversation beneath ShyJ's answer for the rationale.

I find this behavior to be beyond idiotic, and have instead written a very simple alternative. Here's the Kotlin code with a extension function for ArrayLists:

```
class ListIterator<E>(var list: ArrayList<E>) : Iterator<E> {

    private var cursor: Int = 0

    fun replace(newList: ArrayList<E>) {
        list = newList
        cursor = 0
    }

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        return cursor + 1 < list.size
    }

    override fun next(): E {
        cursor++
        return current()
    }

    fun hasPrevious(): Boolean {
        return 0 <= cursor - 1
    }

    fun previous(): E {
        cursor--
        return current()
    }

    fun current(): E {
        return list[cursor]
    }

}

fun <E> ArrayList<E>.listFlippingIterator() = ListIterator(this)
```

If you wish to include removal functionality, I highly recommend writing the API to explicitly instruct the iterator if it should remove left or right, e.g. by defining those methods as `removeNext()` and `removePrevious()`.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this (pseudocode) --

```
class SkipIterator extends ListIterator {

    public E previous(){
        E n = super.previous();
        return super.previous();
    }

    ...

}
```

then:

```
LinkedList<String> navigationCases;
navigationCases.add("page1");
navigationCases.add("page2");
navigationCases.add("page3");
navigationCases.add("page4");

SkipIterator navigationItr = (SkipIterator)navigationCases.listIterator();
navigationItr.next(); // Returns page1
navigationItr.next(); // Returns page2
navigationItr.previous(); // Returns page1
```

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, I only want to call previous() twice iff the previous operation was next().  If next was not called prior, calling previous() twice will actually cause the iterator to skip an element in the list.

Comment: Ok, so build that logic in.  :)  The idea is that you can extend the base class and include the logic you need for your use case.

Comment: Executing `previous()` twice for each invocation will not give the desired behavior when navigating backwards without a prior invocation of `next()`.