# Finding Adjacent Element in ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to create a for loop which if C2 is adjacent (either previous or next in the array) to C then it continues. I am new to working with these and cant figure out how its meant to be done?

I have done the following method to try and find the adjacent elements:

```
    private static List<Station>Adjacent(ArrayList H,Station station)   {
        ListIterator<Station> listIterator = H.listIterator();
```

Comment: Don't use raw types. `ArrayList<Station> H`. Also respect naming conventions.

Comment: Couple of notes: 1- your while loop executes just once in the function 2- you pass variable "station" without using it in the function 3- Use ArrayList<Station> instead of ArrayList

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483035/using-listiterator-to-move-back-and-forth-over-a-linkedlist-in-java This is answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

JavaDoc [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous()) that `previouse()` returns the previouse element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards.

So you don't actually move iterator any further. Try to save previouse item in separate value or use indexes instead of iterator.